# SQL query for movie database

Tags: mysql, sql

Top twenty rated movies (Condition: The movie should be rated/viewed by at least 40 users)? This is my query but It is not giving right result.
This database contains 3 tables:

```
  `select Title 
   from Movie m 
   JOIN
   (select MovieID, Rating 
   from Ratings 
   order by
   Rating)
   as r on 
   m.MovieID = r.MovieID
   limit 20;`
```

Can you suggest the right query?
[This image contains the description of tables. It has 3 tables: Movie, Ratings, Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sug2s.png)

Comment: Provide your table structure, sample data and desired output for people to answer your question!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As @N00bPr0grammer metioned, a great place to start would be providing table structure and sample data.

Comment: Should that be 'Movie AS m'?

Comment: @Robbie the "AS" is optional

Comment: I have added the Image as describing tables in my question was getting ambiguous. Here is the Image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sug2s.png

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN SQL

```
select Title from Movie m  
inner join (select top 20 MovieID,sum(Rating) Rate from Ratings group by movieid having count(UserID)>39 order by sum(Rating) DESC) tbl
on m.MovieID=tbl.MovieID
order by tbl.Rate desc
```

IN MYSQL

```
 select Title from Movie m  
    inner join (select  MovieID,sum(Rating) Rate from Ratings group by movieid having count(UserID)>39 order by sum(Rating) DESC limit 20) tbl
    on m.MovieID=tbl.MovieID
    order by tbl.Rate desc
```

Comment: While this code might solve the problem in the question, the answer can be improved by adding an explanation that describes how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL ORDER BY Keyword. The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set in ascending or descending order. The ORDER BY keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in descending order, use the DESC keyword. For more see [SQL ORDER BY Keyword - W3Schools](https://www.google.cm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHjsywp7jXAhVJuhQKHYSiCgwQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Fsql_orderby.asp&usg=AOvVaw25M3MByQbVIvQV-Kv4SfLm) Doing this and getting the first 20 would meaning getting the top 20 ranking movies.

Another thing is you want to get the top 20 movies, so you could just get them from the `Rating` table before doing the joins. This will reduce the size of the data set before the join, hence optimizing the query.

With those in mind you query should be like:

```
select Title from Movie m JOIN 
(select MovieID, Rating from Ratings order by Rating DESC limit 20) as r
on m.MovieID = r.MovieID;
```

Comment: I need list of those movies that has been rated by at least more than 40 users. So this won't work.

Comment: More information on the database schema is needed to do this. Is there a table that keeps track of the number of users that have rated a movies?

Comment: Is there an association table between `Ranking` and some `user` table in your schema?